# How to solve MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php in laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5.3

My view is like this :

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['users.store.year.month', $year, $month]]) !!}                
    @include('users.fields')
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

My route is like this :

```
Route::get('users/store/{year}/{month}', 'UserController@store')
        ->name('users.store.year.month');
```

My controller is like this :

```
public function store(CreateTunkinRequest $request, $thang, $month)
{
    ...
    return redirect(route('users.proses', ['month' => $month, 'year' => $year]));
}
```

When I input data and save, there exist error like this :

> MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:

How can I solve it?

Comment: Where is `users.proses` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using laravel collective by default, a POST method will be assumed, so change your form to

`{!! Form::open(['route' => ['users.store.year.month', $year, $month] , 'method' => 'get']) !!}`

See https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.3/html#opening-a-form

Answer (score 0):

You may get this error, when you are making a GET request on a POST route, or vice versa. You are using `Route::get`, but your form's default method is POST.